# How do I need read a file with commas and words and only store numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, jframe, stringtokenizer

I need to store only numbers that have 8 digits and not a word into an array, and if it is not then just to print it to the console. Once in the array i have to sort them and print them into the right side and the left side has the unsorted list.

So I am stuck at a file with commas it only works when it has not commas or space. I am supposed to use the method "compareTo" and the "StringTokenizer" I know how they both work but just does not do what i want, maybe I am putting it in the wrong function. I also need to separate this file and put in a separate file the GUI functions not sure what to put on that file.

```
public class Project1 {
static final int LIST_SIZE = 10;
static int ssnSize;
static String line;
static String[] ssnList;
static TextFileInput inFile;
static String inFileName = "Dates.txt"; //save the file in Lab12 folder on BB in your project folder
static JFrame myFrame;
static Container myContentPane;
static TextArea left, right;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialize();
    readNumbersFromFile(inFileName);
    printSSNList(ssnList,ssnSize);
    printSSNtoJFrame(myFrame,ssnSize);
}

public static void initialize() {
    inFile = new TextFileInput(inFileName);
    ssnList= new String[LIST_SIZE];
    ssnSize=0;
    line ="";
    left = new TextArea();
    right = new TextArea();
    myFrame = new JFrame();
    myFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    myFrame.setLocation(200, 200);
    myFrame.setTitle("");
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void readNumbersFromFile(String fileName)
{
       String ssn;
       ssn = inFile.readLine();
       while (ssn != null) {
          assert (isValidDate(ssn)): "SSN not valid";
          if (!isValidDate(ssn))
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid SSN");
          else
              storeDates(ssn,ssnList);
          ssn = inFile.readLine();
       } //while

} //readSSNsFromFile

public static void printSSNList(String[] list, int size)
{
       assert (isValidList(list)): "The array is not valid";
       if (!isValidList(list)){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid list)");
       }
       for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
           if (!isValidDate(list[i]))
               System.out.println("Invalid SSN: "+list[i]);
           else
               System.out.println(list[i]);
}

public static void storeDates(String s, String[] list)
{
       assert (isValidDate(s)): "The SSN is not valid";
       assert (isValidList(list)): "The array is not valid";

       if (isValidDate(s) && isValidList(list))
          list[ssnSize++]=s;
       assert (isValidList(list)):"Resulting list not valid";
}

public static void printSSNtoJFrame(JFrame jf, int size)
{
       assert (isValidList(ssnList)): "The array is not valid";
       if (!isValidList(ssnList)){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid list)");
       }

       jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
       myContentPane = jf.getContentPane();
       TextArea myLeftArea = new TextArea();
       TextArea myRightTextArea = new TextArea();
       myContentPane.add(myLeftArea);
       myContentPane.add(myRightTextArea);


        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
               if (!isValidDate(ssnList[i]))
                   myLeftArea.append("Invalid SSN: "+ssnList[i]+"\n");
               else
               {
                   myLeftArea.append(ssnList[i]+"\n");
               }
        }


        sortOnlyNumbers(ssnList);

        for(int j=0; j< size; j++)
        {
               myRightTextArea.append(ssnList[j]+"\n");
        }
        jf.setVisible(true);
} 

private static void sortOnlyNumbers(String[] array)
{
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        try {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(array[i]));
            indexes.add(i);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // don't care
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        array[indexes.get(i)] = String.valueOf(numbers.get(i));
    }
}

public static boolean isValidDate(String s)
{
       if (s.length() != 8) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("An SSN length must be 9");
       }
       for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
           if (! Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("SSN must have only digits.");
       }
       return (true);
}

public static boolean isValidList(String[] list)
{
       if (list == null){
          return false;
       }
       if (ssnSize == list.length){
          return false;
       }
       return (true);
}
```

}

the text file has the following:

> 20161001
>   20080912,20131120,19980927, \n
>   20020202,hello
>   20120104

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to perform this. An appropriate one for your requirement would be:

`(\d{8})`

This regex matches groups of 8 consecutive digits in your input data.

I tested this using the snippet below and was able to retrieve all 8-digit numbers from your input string.

```
public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "20161001 20080912,20131120,19980927, \n 20020202,hello 20120104";
        List<String> matches = get8DigitNumbersOnly(input);
        System.out.println(matches);
    }

    public static List<String> get8DigitNumbersOnly(String inputData) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{8})"); // This is the regex.
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputData);
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            matches.add(match);
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

Give it as shot. Hope this helps!